# Do GPUs have a noticeable improvement in ML predictions? (not training)

Tags: machine-learning, gpu

I interested in improving performance with regard to ML predictions. (I don't care about training)
-Will GPUs provide more throughput or lower latency?
-Are they good for batch or online serving?
-What types of models would be most impact by using GPUs?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: The real answer is **"it depends; if such a decision is important to you, you should benchmark CPU performance against GPU performance on your target systems to make an informed decision."** The rest of this answer is just advice to loosely guide your decision when you don't want to (or don't have time to) do any benchmarking.

In a research environment, predictions are often (though not always) done in batches. As such, even if the model is entirely serial (i.e. there is an execution dependency between every pair of operations), it will likely *still* benefit from parallelization in that those serial operations may have to be replicated for multiple query points simultaneously, and so you can parallelize predictions across query points within a batch. So if your prediction setting involves batches, you should pretty much always use a GPU. From my own research experiences, a GPU is always faster than a CPU in batched prediction settings, regardless of the model used.

If you are only making a single prediction at a time (e.g. an "online" prediction setting), most modern ML methods are still highly parallelizable in general. In a neural network, for instance, there are only execution dependencies between layers; there are no execution dependencies between nodes within a layer. If you have many nodes per layer (which most modern deep learning architectures do), then your model is likely very parallelizable and can benefit from using a GPU instead of a CPU.

Naive Bayes classifiers make predictions by computing a bunch of (supposedly) conditionally independent probabilities, which can be parallelized, and then multiplying them together, which can be parallelized via reduction. As such, they may also benefit from using a GPU instead of a CPU.

For a support vector machine with the dual problem approach, making a prediction requires computing an inner product (kernel trick) for each training data point with the query point, and multiplying each inner product by the corresponding parameters and target binary labels. This can very easily be parallelized in a similar way to naive Bayes classifiers.

The list goes on. The point is, most ML methods are at least relatively conducive to parallelization even if you're processing a single query point at a time, and extremely conducive to parallelization if you're processing query points in batch.  This makes them generally run faster on the "average" GPU than the "average" CPU.

**But ultimately, it depends on your model and target system, so if it matters that much to you, you should benchmark to make an informed decision.**